# Add an extra flag in ES query to check if a field exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing a query to get some records like this:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_search?from=0&size=30&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "content:(aid OR hiv)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "content",
    "entity_avatar_link",
    "author_link",
    "name"
  ],
  size: 30,
  from: 0
}
```

This much is working fine and I am getting the results.

I am trying to add a script field (which acts a flag) which returns whether a field exists in the doc along with every doc returned (I cannot return the field, as in most cases, it will be a very large size (an embedded field)). So, I added this also to the query:

```
"script_fields": {
    "is_arranged_flag": {
      "script": "!_source.arranged_retweets.empty"
    }
  }
```

So the whole query will be like:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_search?from=0&size=30&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "content:(aid OR hiv)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "content",
    "entity_avatar_link",
    "author_link",
    "name"
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "is_arranged_flag": {
      "script": "!_source.arranged_retweets.empty"
    }
  }
  size: 30,
  from: 0
}
```

But after adding the `script_fields` section, no result is coming out (results is empty [] for the same search query).

I have also tried:

```
 "script_fields": {
    "is_arranged_flag": {
      "script": "!doc['arranged_retweets'].empty"
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the mapping `http://localhost:9200/posts/post/_mapping`

```
{
  "post": {
    "properties": {
      "arranged_retweets": {
        "properties": {
          "author_gender": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "author_link": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "tweet_analyzer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "index_options": "docs"
      },
      "author_link": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "index_options": "docs"
      },
      "entity_avatar_link": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "index_options": "docs"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of the discussion here (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/BJZdlFSJSRg). The field arranged_retweets is an object. So, we need to check down to the inner level `arranged_retweets.author_gender` and check if it is empty like this:

```
"script_fields": {
   "is_arranged_flag": {
      "script": "!doc['arranged_retweets.author_gender'].empty"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the valid `script_fields` segment.

```
"script_fields": {
   "is_arranged_flag": {
      "script": "!doc['arranged_retweets'].empty"
   }
}
```

Reference: [scripting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) (Read the section on document fields)

Comment: sorry, I had mistakenly pasted the wrong code in the question. I have updated with the real code, which is same as this.